# ¿Porque JSF me genera el siguiente código?

Tags: java, jsf

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo a usar JSF. Tengo en mi index el siguiente codigo

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="nombre" value="Nombre: "/>
            <h:inputText id="nombre" value="#{candidato.nombre}"/>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

El cual, como verán, me llena un input con un valor que traigo de un **ManagedBean**. Al inspeccionar el código de mi formulario en el navegador se ve lo siguiente

```
<form id="j_idt5" name="j_idt5" method="post" action="/holamundojsf/faces/index.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="j_idt5" value="j_idt5" />
    <label for="j_idt5:nombre">Nombre: </label>
    <input id="j_idt5:nombre" type="text" name="j_idt5:nombre" value="Lucas" />
    <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="5653048738680287774:4897922820580699689" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

No comprendo porque se generan cosas que yo no he definido, tales como **inputs hidden** y atributos con el valor de **j_idt5**.

Comment: Creo que eso se genera porque tanto el formulario como los labels y el input requieren de los  atributos id y for respectivamente

Answer (score 0):

Las etiquetas de JSF abstraen al desarrollador de cuestiones relacionadas con código html pero, como puedes ver, acaban siendo traducidas a código html puro y duro que es lo que entiende el navegador.